# Computing percentage between three tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a relationship between three tables. I need to compute the percentage score of every individual who has taken the survey. My table structure is as follows:

### Surveyanswers

survey_answer_id
user_id
question_idanswer_voted

### possibleanswers

possible_answer_id
question_id
answer

### questions

question_id

question

question_group_id

When a person takes the survey questions, the answers are posted on `surveyanswers` table as `answer_voted`. The value of the `answer_voted` is the same as `possible_answer_id` which is a primary key in `possibleanswers` table.

Comment: Which code have you tried so far ? We are not here to do your homework, show some effort.

Comment: Please post some data, expected result and what you have tried so far

Comment: Define "percentage score"

Comment: So far my query displays all the needed fields and below is the query itself

Comment: SELECT sa.userid
    , sa.question_id
    ,q.question_group_id
    , sa.answer_voted
    , pa.possible_answer_id
    ,pa.answer
FROM surveyanswers sa
INNER JOIN possibleanswers pa
    on  pa.possible_answer_id = sa.answer_voted
INNER JOIN questions q
    on q.question_id = sa.question_id;

Comment: Its a survey..it has 6 tabs,each tab has a set of questions..the tabs are agile,people,environment,organizational,procurement and communication
 when a user takes the survey he starts with agile all the way to communication..at the end of the survey,he needs a percentage score of all the 6 tabs ie agile-40%,people-20% and so on.
 Am currently on first tab called agile..it has a total of 19 qstns..the answer options are -2,-1,1,2,3..when a user answers all the 19 qstns i need to sum all the answers together to find his/her total points..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally managed..Thanks you guyz..i shall post my code here just incase anyone finds a similar problem..Good day mates!

```
 SELECT sa.userid
 ,q.question_group_id
   ,sum(pa.answer)/(select
   count(q.question)*3)*100 as 'Percentage'
FROM surveyanswers sa
INNER JOIN possibleanswers pa
on  pa.possible_answer_id = sa.answer_voted


INNER JOIN questions q
on q.question_id = sa.question_id


 where userid=7
and q.question_group_id=1;
```